# Data not showing React Axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am trying to get data using axios but it doesn't seem to load onto the page.  I have used the link in postman and retrieves all the data so I assume the get request from the server is fine but when used in the jsx file it shows no data
here is my jsx file

#### index.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import axios from 'axios'

export default function App() {
    const client = axios.create({
        baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/api/getUser" 
      });
      const [users, setPosts] = useState([]);

      useEffect(() => {
         client.get('?_limit=10').then((response) => {
            setPosts(response.data);
         });
      }, []);

  return (
    <div className="app">
    <h2>All Users </h2>
    {users && users.length > 0 && users.map(({id, post}) => {
       return (
          <div className="post-card" key = {id}>
             <h2 className="post-title">{post.email}</h2>
             <p className="post-body">{post.firstName}</p>
             <div className="button">
                <div className="delete-btn">Delete</div>
             </div>
          </div>
       );
    })}
  </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Here it is`{status: 'Success', data: {…}}
data: {userDetails: Array(3)}
status: "Success"
[[Prototype]]: Object`

Comment: i think you just need to change  setPosts(response.data) to setPosts(response?.data?.data) ;

Comment: I have changed it but the data still doesn't show

Comment: here is the full json 
` {"status":"Success","data":{"userDetails":[{"_id":"62fb9702540785002e5fc5fd","firstName":"testname1","lastName":"testsurname","email":"test123@test.com","password":"$2b$10$Kn/2VNNE7Q.HEsYSMgBk0u29r26SQ/AVQLGTuSvxj/rbB1o/Y9os2","__v":0},{"_id":"62fbb48aff187fc897d86147","firstName":"test","lastName":"test2","email":"test1234@test.com","password":"$2b$10$ZpOQihEkTHBMTKG1ZrWY2uuMVn/fK6Pp9QKc7RGgIxBdd/kdAuUti","__v":0}]}}`

Comment: The code works perfect but how do I parse my data from the db like you did with the json?

Comment: `  useEffect(() => {
         client.get("?_limit=10").then((response) => {
            const responseData = JSON.stringify(response.data);

            console.log(responseData);
            setPosts(responseData.data.userDetails);
         });
      }, []);
`
I am getting this error in the console 

_TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'userDetails')_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have answer instead of comments:

Error was due to data from API was coming with different structure, as per comments, `JSON.stringify(response.data)` was

```
{
  "status": "Success",
  "data": {
    "userDetails": [
      {
        "_id": "62fb9702540785002e5fc5fd",
        "firstName": "testname1",
        "lastName": "testsurname",
        "email": "test123@test.com",
        "password": "$2b$10$Kn/2VNNE7Q.HEsYSMgBk0u29r26SQ/AVQLGTuSvxj/rbB1o/Y9os2",
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "62fbb48aff187fc897d86147",
        "firstName": "test",
        "lastName": "test2",
        "email": "test1234@test.com",
        "password": "$2b$10$ZpOQihEkTHBMTKG1ZrWY2uuMVn/fK6Pp9QKc7RGgIxBdd/kdAuUti",
        "__v": 0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So in order to set a list to a state the correct code should look like that:

```
setPosts(response.data.data.userDetails);
```

Next issue: destructuring of the map function was invalid. You have to destructure the exact properties you have in your object:

```
<div className="app">
  <h2>All Users </h2>
  {users &&
    users.length > 0 &&
    users.map(({ _id, firstName, lastName, email, password }) => {
      return (
        <div className="post-card" key={_id}>
          <h2 className="post-title">{email}</h2>
          <p className="post-body">{firstName}</p>
          <p className="post-body">{lastName}</p>
          <p className="post-body">{password}</p>
          <div className="button">
            <div className="delete-btn">Delete</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    })}
</div>
```

Comment: @DariusElijah Sure, but always check what comes to you from the API, start using `debugger;` and `console.log` more frequently. Also, please, do not forget to accept the answers so your question will not appear in our list as question without accepted answer, also +rep to me :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Check your response data structures before updating the `App` component state.

Postcard UI can be shown if the item of the `users` array exists.

I looking at the previous answer, and I think it can be fixed with the below codes.

```
setPosts(response.data.userDetails);
```